# C++ like c# regex match function

Tags: c#, c++, regex

How to convert this code to c++? I work with std::regex. Need start position give to std::regex_match.

My like c# regex code:

```
Regex myreg  = new Regex("pattern");

string input = "data";
int startat = 0;

myreg.Match(input, startat);
```

Comment: Don't think that just because C# gives the class `Regex` a method named `Match`, and just because C++ provides a function `regex_match`, that they do the same thing. They don't, and if you need to translate what you have to C++, then contrary to what you wrote in your question, `std::regex_match` is not what you should be using. So which is it? Do you need to use `std::regex_match`, or do you need to translate what you have to C++?

Comment: Why don't you give it a try and if you run into problems, then ask a question about the specific problem you are having